# How to list all installed Jupyter kernels?

Tags: python, conda

Listing all the available environments is as simple as:

```
$ conda env list
```

Now how does one list the currently installed kernels, without having to go to the path:

```
$ ls /home/{{user}}/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/
```

Answer (score 140, accepted):

With Jupyter installed you get the list of currently installed kernels with:

```
$ jupyter kernelspec list

python2     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/resources
testenv     /home/{{user}}/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/sparkenv
```

Answer (score 2):

For those that come here because VSCode can't find the kernel although it is shown when using `jupyter kernelspec list`, try updating `pyzmq`.

```bash
pip install pyzmq --upgrade
```

---

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72937056/11671779)