# Failed to start the Kernel - Jupyter in VS Code

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I am trying to use a Jupyter notebook for some Pandas in VS Code. I set up a virtual environment venv where I installed Pandas and jupyter. I always did it like this and it worked fine. But suddenly it does not work anymore.
[Code with error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9GKb.png)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Could you try to reinstall the `pyzmq` module?

```
pip uninstall pyzmq
pip install pyzmq==19.0.2
```

Comment: Get the reason why this is the answer from another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72937056/11671779).

Answer (score 23):

I got the same error message because the jupyter package was missing in my selected environment.

```
pip install jupyter
```

resolved the problem for me.

From the official [VS Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks):

> To work with Python in Jupyter Notebooks, **you must activate an**
> Anaconda environment in VS Code, or another Python **environment in
> which you've installed the Jupyter package.**

Comment: This worked for me on Windows laptop. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately I tried some options previously provided but none of them worked.

```
pip install pyzmq==19.0.2 
pip install jupyter
```

Only thing that worked was to go to the Jupyter extension in VS CODE and change from Release Version to Pre-Release version and reload the program.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

**Update to Steven-MSFT's solution:**

```
pip uninstall pyzmq        #Steven-MSFT's solution
pip install pyzmq==19.0.2

pip install pyzmq          #Update
```

**Explanation:**

Installing 19.0.2 (after uninstalling) produced an error ..

*jupyter-client 7.3.4 requires pyzmq>=23.0, but you have pyzmq 19.0.2 which is incompatible.*

.. updating pyzmq to the latest version (23.2.0 at time of writing) by running *pip install pyzmq* resolved this error. I was originally on the latest version, so i'm not sure why this procedure of reverting and then reupgrading works
¯\*(ツ)*/¯

Answer (score 4):

I faced a similar problem for the last couple of days and tried almost all the solutions available including the following

- Re-installing `conda`, `python`, `jupyter`, VS-code.
- Updating `pyzmq` and many other suggested packages and dependencies.
- Trying running on a local server (which worked but was not what I was looking for)

Finally what worked was simply switching the Jupyter extension in VS Code to the Pre-release version.
[Jupyter Extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9oDO.png)

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to run the kernel in a separate terminal (using the `jupyter notebook` command), and to connect to that kernel from VS Code (Click on "Jupyter Server: local" and choose the kernel running on localhost from the list).

Answer (score 0):

Building off the work of @Steven-MSFT and @Con O'Leary, try:

`pip install --upgrade pyzmq`

This upgrades the `pyzmq` package. As @Con O'Leary notes, recent versions of jupyter-client require more more recent versions of pyzmq.

Answer (score 0):

I clicked in extensions, selected Jupyter, and there was a reload button behind it. It worked after I clocked it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of things but the only thing that worked was switching to a pre-release version of jupyter in the extensions tab and reloading.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat related. I got an error regarding the `pyzmq` module needing to be reinstalled. In the end, I ended up having a file in my folder structure that was conflicting with an import (as in I had `random.py` which was conflicting with the import for the `random` import.)

I would just check to make sure that you have no files that could lead to such an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well after  un-installation and installation of VSCode, conda and the like from my Linux PC, I too faced this and was wondering

Basically, I had to install Python again. Looks so obvious and I am not a newbie.. still

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python

Cntrl+P

```
ext install ms-python.python
```

Answer (score 0):

Saw it has something to do with sockets, try upgrading tornado by this simple command
`pip install jupyter`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had 3 python installations -
Installed Pythons found by py Launcher for Windows
-3.10-64 *
-3.9-64
-3.7-64

Using v 3.9 I created virtual environment and tried to run jupyter notebook code and got same error

After digging into the issue for sometime, I found that I had done installation of Anaconda and python v 3.9 was installed in anaconda.
While creating virtual environment, I used non-conda commands for conda installed python version, that was causing the issue.
After removing VE and reinstalling with v3.10 with non-conda commands, I am able to work in VSCode with jupyter nb for the environment.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35638779)