# kernel failed to start using conda environment with Jupyter in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter

When using a Jupyter notebook file in Visual Studio code with the Jupyter extension I receive the error `The kernel failed to start due to the missing module 'ipykernel_launcher'. Consider installing this module.  View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.`

This notebook works correctly from the JupyterLab web application when I select the same conda environment that was selected in Visual Studio Code.

`pip list` shows that ipykernel version 5.3.4 is installed, but I don't know how to install ipykernel_launcher. I tried [reinstalling pyzmq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70517240/4726729) and it didn't help.

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Had the same problem. My solution is --

First uninstall all jupyter related modules:

```
python3 -m pip uninstall -y jupyter jupyter_core jupyter-client jupyter-console jupyterlab_pygments notebook qtconsole nbconvert nbformat jupyterlab-widgets nbclient ipykernel ipynb
```

(from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52912244/1516331)

And then reinstall `ipykernel`. I'm using VScode so when I run a cell, VSCode asked me to install`ipykernel`. The following should work the same alternatively:

```
conda install -c conda-forge --update-deps --force-reinstall ipykernel -y
```

Comment: Thanks! Uninstalling and then letting VSCode reinstall the extensions as you describe fixed my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the uninstall and install packages, I found I have to do "conda update --all" twice to get problem solved.