# Failed to start Jupyter in the environment 'Python 3.9.6' - VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I've just got a new mac, installs vscode, open a .ipynb file and presses the 'install jupyter notebook extension' pop up button. But now I'm getting this error when I try to run cells:

`Failed to start Jupyter in the environment 'Python 3.9.6'. View Jupyter log for further details`

Here's the log

```
info 12:09:29.628: Starting Jupyter Session startUsingPythonInterpreter, .jvsc74a57bd031f2aee4e71d21fbe5cf8b01ff0e069b9275f58929596ceb00d14d90e3e16cd6./usr/bin/python3./usr/bin/python3.-m#ipykernel_launcher (Python Path: , EnvType: Unknown, EnvName: '', Version: 3.9.6 (default, Oct 18 2022, 12:41:40) 
[Clang 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)]) for '/Users/wibe/Desktop/CogSci/Language_analytics/cds-language/nbs/session04_inclass_JHW.ipynb' (disableUI=false)
info 12:09:29.628: Checking for server existence.
info 12:09:29.628: Connecting to server
info 12:09:29.628: Launching server
info 12:09:29.629: Starting Notebook
info 12:09:29.630: Generating custom default config at /var/folders/r8/gsxkw58x4kb27824mzyy6l9w0000gn/T/597fa943-83d7-4ddc-95a8-970ba34f29dc/jupyter_notebook_config.py
Starting Jupyter from /usr/bin/python3 with arguments --no-browser --notebook-dir="/Users/wibe/Desktop/CogSci/Language_analytics/cds-language/nbs" --config=/var/folders/r8/gsxkw58x4kb27824mzyy6l9w0000gn/T/597fa943-83d7-4ddc-95a8-970ba34f29dc/jupyter_notebook_config.py --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=10000000000.0
info 12:09:29.683: Process Execution: > /usr/bin/python3 -m jupyter notebook --no-browser --notebook-dir="/Users/wibe/Desktop/CogSci/Language_analytics/cds-language/nbs" --config=/var/folders/r8/gsxkw58x4kb27824mzyy6l9w0000gn/T/597fa943-83d7-4ddc-95a8-970ba34f29dc/jupyter_notebook_config.py --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=10000000000.0
> /usr/bin/python3 -m jupyter notebook --no-browser --notebook-dir="/Users/wibe/Desktop/CogSci/Language_analytics/cds-language/nbs" --config=/var/folders/r8/gsxkw58x4kb27824mzyy6l9w0000gn/T/597fa943-83d7-4ddc-95a8-970ba34f29dc/jupyter_notebook_config.py --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=10000000000.0
usage: jupyter.py [-h] [--version] [--config-dir] [--data-dir] [--runtime-dir]
                  [--paths] [--json] [--debug]
                  [subcommand]

Jupyter: Interactive Computing

positional arguments:
  subcommand     the subcommand to launch

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  --version      show the versions of core jupyter packages and exit
  --config-dir   show Jupyter config dir
  --data-dir     show Jupyter data dir
  --runtime-dir  show Jupyter runtime dir
  --paths        show all Jupyter paths. Add --json for machine-readable
                 format.
  --json         output paths as machine-readable json
  --debug        output debug information about paths

Available subcommands:

Jupyter command `jupyter-notebook` not found.
warn 12:09:29.745: Error occurred while trying to start the kernel, options.disableUI=false Er [Error]: Jupyter server crashed. Unable to connect. 
Error code from Jupyter: 1
usage: jupyter.py [-h] [--version] [--config-dir] [--data-dir] [--runtime-dir]
                  [--paths] [--json] [--debug]
                  [subcommand]

Jupyter: Interactive Computing

positional arguments:
  subcommand     the subcommand to launch

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  --version      show the versions of core jupyter packages and exit
  --config-dir   show Jupyter config dir
  --data-dir     show Jupyter data dir
  --runtime-dir  show Jupyter runtime dir
  --paths        show all Jupyter paths. Add --json for machine-readable
                 format.
  --json         output paths as machine-readable json
  --debug        output debug information about paths

Available subcommands:

Jupyter command `jupyter-notebook` not found.

    at Sm.rejectStartPromise (/Users/wibe/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:17:254981)
    at t._complete (/Users/wibe/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:17:255541)
    at t.n (/Users/wibe/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:2:700797)
    at t.__tryOrUnsub (/Users/wibe/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:2:701037)
    at t.complete (/Users/wibe/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:2:700930)
    at t._complete (/Users/wibe/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:2:699446)
    at t.complete (/Users/wibe/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:2:699145)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/wibe/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:2:1800927)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:646:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:538:35)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12) {
  category: 'jupyterconnection'
}
warn 12:09:29.745: Kernel Error, context = start Er [Error]: Jupyter server crashed. Unable to connect. 
Error code from Jupyter: 1
usage: jupyter.py [-h] [--version] [--config-dir] [--data-dir] [--runtime-dir]
                  [--paths] [--json] [--debug]
                  [subcommand]

Jupyter: Interactive Computing

positional arguments:
  subcommand     the subcommand to launch

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  --version      show the versions of core jupyter packages and exit
  --config-dir   show Jupyter config dir
  --data-dir     show Jupyter data dir
  --runtime-dir  show Jupyter runtime dir
  --paths        show all Jupyter paths. Add --json for machine-readable
                 format.
  --json         output paths as machine-readable json
  --debug        output debug information about paths

Available subcommands:

Jupyter command `jupyter-notebook` not found.

    at Sm.rejectStartPromise (/Users/wibe/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:17:254981)
    at t._complete (/Users/wibe/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:17:255541)
    at t.n (/Users/wibe/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:2:700797)
    at t.__tryOrUnsub (/Users/wibe/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:2:701037)
    at t.complete (/Users/wibe/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:2:700930)
    at t._complete (/Users/wibe/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:2:699446)
    at t.complete (/Users/wibe/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:2:699145)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/wibe/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:2:1800927)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:646:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:538:35)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12) {
  category: 'jupyterconnection'
}
info 12:09:29.750: Process Execution: > /usr/bin/python3 -c "import ipykernel;print('6af208d0-cb9c-427f-b937-ff563e17efdf')"
> /usr/bin/python3 -c "import ipykernel;print('6af208d0-cb9c-427f-b937-ff563e17efdf')"
info 12:09:29.858: Dispose Kernel '/Users/wibe/Desktop/CogSci/Language_analytics/cds-language/nbs/session04_inclass_JHW.ipynb' associated with '/Users/wibe/Desktop/CogSci/Language_analytics/cds-language/nbs/session04_inclass_JHW.ipynb'
error 12:09:29.860: Error in execution Er [Error]: Jupyter server crashed. Unable to connect. 
Error code from Jupyter: 1
usage: jupyter.py [-h] [--version] [--config-dir] [--data-dir] [--runtime-dir]
                  [--paths] [--json] [--debug]
                  [subcommand]

Jupyter: Interactive Computing

positional arguments:
  subcommand     the subcommand to launch

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  --version      show the versions of core jupyter packages and exit
  --config-dir   show Jupyter config dir
  --data-dir     show Jupyter data dir
  --runtime-dir  show Jupyter runtime dir
  --paths        show all Jupyter paths. Add --json for machine-readable
                 format.
  --json         output paths as machine-readable json
  --debug        output debug information about paths

Available subcommands:

Jupyter command `jupyter-notebook` not found.

    at Sm.rejectStartPromise (/Users/wibe/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:17:254981)
    at t._complete (/Users/wibe/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:17:255541)
    at t.n (/Users/wibe/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:2:700797)
    at t.__tryOrUnsub (/Users/wibe/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:2:701037)
    at t.complete (/Users/wibe/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:2:700930)
    at t._complete (/Users/wibe/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:2:699446)
    at t.complete (/Users/wibe/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:2:699145)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/wibe/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:2:1800927)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:646:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:538:35)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12) {
  category: 'jupyterconnection'
}
error 12:09:29.860: Error in execution (get message for cell) Er [Error]: Jupyter server crashed. Unable to connect. 
Error code from Jupyter: 1
usage: jupyter.py [-h] [--version] [--config-dir] [--data-dir] [--runtime-dir]
                  [--paths] [--json] [--debug]
                  [subcommand]

Jupyter: Interactive Computing

positional arguments:
  subcommand     the subcommand to launch

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  --version      show the versions of core jupyter packages and exit
  --config-dir   show Jupyter config dir
  --data-dir     show Jupyter data dir
  --runtime-dir  show Jupyter runtime dir
  --paths        show all Jupyter paths. Add --json for machine-readable
                 format.
  --json         output paths as machine-readable json
  --debug        output debug information about paths

Available subcommands:

Jupyter command `jupyter-notebook` not found.

    at Sm.rejectStartPromise (/Users/wibe/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:17:254981)
    at t._complete (/Users/wibe/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:17:255541)
    at t.n (/Users/wibe/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:2:700797)
    at t.__tryOrUnsub (/Users/wibe/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:2:701037)
    at t.complete (/Users/wibe/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:2:700930)
    at t._complete (/Users/wibe/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:2:699446)
    at t.complete (/Users/wibe/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:2:699145)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/wibe/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:2:1800927)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:646:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:538:35)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12) {
  category: 'jupyterconnection'
}
```

I have looked all over the web but haven't been able to find any solutions to this. Others has reported similar issues, but their solutions didn't work for me.

Comment: Does the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70506366/failed-to-start-the-kernel-jupyter-in-vs-code) help?

Comment: Also related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/12723 . Could be the same issue, if you can find the relevant log file and compare that with the linked issue.

Comment: @9769953 I've added the full log now, sorry. // Unfortunately it does not solve my issue

Comment: This solved the issue: ```python3 -m pip install jupyter notebook -U --force-reinstall```

Comment: I think that was [one of the earlier suggestions in the GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/12723#issuecomment-1415700340), correct? It's a tad odd the issue is closed, if you recently had a fresh install and ran into exactly this issue.

Comment: Yes, it was one of the earlier suggestions. And you're right, it is actually odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my issue:

`python3 -m pip install jupyter notebook -U --force-reinstall`