Visual Studio Code is throwing Bad File descriptor for any notebook run
Visual studio code (VS Code) is not running ipython notebook.
What I did,

VS Code autocreated the .venv from python 3.12.3 global kernal
It installed all necessary dependencies like jupyter
I installed pandas using pip3 because I need that.
When I try to run any cell it shows the error in screenshot

Error screenshot
The logs shows like this
22:14:06.516 [error] Error in execution Error: The kernel died. Error: Bad file descriptor (C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpw8fxpxar\build\_deps\bundled_libzmq-src\src\epoll.cpp:73)... View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.

This path C:\Users\runneradmin doesn't exists too.
Want to know if I am doing anything wrong here?

I have tried installing all sort of Pip install -U jypyter and other stuffs available online
tried installing and uninstalling python env itself
tried global env and vistual environment, tried activating it manually too


There's a similar issue in github. This seems to be a pyzmq problem.
You could try to run the following codes to reinstall pyzmq in your terminal and wait for the latest version fix:
python -m pip uninstall pyzmq
pip install pyzmq==25.1.2


Note that this is not the first time a problem with pyzmq has arisen where the solution is to fallback to another version of it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70506366/failed-to-start-the-kernel-jupyter-in-vs-code

Just confirming a win- I had updated a bunch of packages only to face an inoperable kernel; downgrading worked.

This worked for me. Interestingly, I had to use this fix every single time I launched the notebook, which was annoying.

I uninstalled the ms store python app.
Downloaded python from the python.org site
Installed the python .exe file and added it to PATH during installation
Installed the jupyter notebook again
Added the jupyter notebook to PATH as well

and everything worked. Launched the Jupyter notebook and no more bad file descriptor error.
